# How to restrict .exe file to run from C# WPF app only

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process

I have an WPF applications which is used to download several application and run those applications from this wpf app.(Can think of as similar to "Windows Store app")

Now I need to restrict the other application exe files that are downloaded from my wpf app to only run from my wpf app. If user tries to run the exe from files system it should prompt an error message saying restricted access.

How can I lock the exe to run from only my app after downloading it from my wpf app.
How can I achieve this in C# WPF app?

Comment: If you need a somehow "naive" protection then yes, what Youri suggested is OK (just consider to use an hashcode instead of a plain string to make things little bit more difficult...). If you need more then sign your host assembly, for each "client" get the parent process and check its public key.

Comment: Sry I am new to .net development , I didn't get what u said after "if u need more...."

Comment: I mean if you want to be (little bit more) sure that they don't run those applications with the right command line simply inspecting your assembly with dotPeek ("they" just need to disassemble and see what's the required _secret_ parameter). If it's your own process that verifies its own signed assembly parent then to circumvent this limitation is harder (it's ALWAYS possible but less easy and it may exclude _casual crackers_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have acces to the source code of the exes? Cause then you can add some sort of login to the downloaded exe.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     if (args[0] != "password")
     {
         Environment.Exit(0);
     }
}
```

In case you don't have acces to the source code of the downloaded exes you can use this solution. This does require to have the application running at all times.
bool notepadopened = false;

```
while (true)
{
     foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"))
     {
          if (!notepadopened && p.ProcessName.ToString() == "notepad")
          {
               p.Kill();
          }
     }
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have access to source code of exe.

Comment: Good then you can pass a password as command line argument and check it when starting the exe.

Comment: How to check  the password and stop the exe to launch.

Comment: I am using `Process.StartProcess()` to launch the .exe file

Comment: Please view my updated answer. And I mean the that you need to acces the source code of exes you download. Not the exe that downloads the exes.

Comment: Yeah thanks :) . Is it possible even if don't have access to source code of exe.

Comment: I saw some pdf that prompt for password when I try to open then. Similar ones ?

Comment: Well you could do that. You could have a boolean in your application that states if the executed the exe. Then check every second if the exe is run. If so and the application has the boolean to false then you have to kill the exe

Comment: No your password is set in the source code of your exes

Comment: Yeah Thank u,  but that solutions seems worst case solution right(fast solution that i can have).

Comment: Yes you generaly don't want to do this unless no other option remains

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140035/discussion-between-djkp-and-youri-leenman).